# Create a Dynamic Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a html snippet that I'm now having to duplicate a lot which brings me to my question as I'd like to make the html snippet into a directive that can be reused.
I'd like to transform the snippet below into a directive.

```
  <a href="#"
    ng-click="vm.orderBy ='UserName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                                    User Name
                                    <span ng-show="vm.orderBy == 'UserName'">
                                        <span ng-show="!reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"></i></span>
                                        <span ng-show="reverseSort"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i></span>
                                    </span>
    </a>
```

What I'd  like is a directive that allows me to pass any  string property to the orderBy field which would make it dynamic.
so something like `<my-directive sort = 'Username'></my-directive>`
I have  `vm.orderBy = ''` initialised in my main controller.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What version of angularjs are you using? Maybe better to use [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) instead of directive for this purpose?
Have you tried looking into [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive)? There are a lot of examples how to use templates with directives/components; SO is not a resource for a free code writing (but you are just asking to write a directive for you), so you should make a minimal research first and provide some more information, before asking this.

Comment: I don't even see a question mark in your "question".

Comment: @ Stanislav as you probably can see , I answered my own question on a second look. I do not need a lesson on how SO works I've been here for a good minute. And just as a side note SO is not for people who want to go off on a power trip . There are better ways to pass your point across and not make assumptions that you are not sure of. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.module('app_name', []).directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ["$scope"];  // dependecny injection

function myDirective($scope) {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'mydir.tmpl.html',
        scope: {
            sort: "@"
        }
     }
}
```

**mydir.tmpl.html**

```
  <a href="#" ng-click="vm.orderBy=sort; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
           User Name
           <span ng-show="vm.orderBy == sort">
              <span ng-show="!reverseSort">
                  <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"></i>
              </span>
              <span ng-show="reverseSort">
                  <i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i>
              </span>
          </span>
    </a>
```

Then use

`<my-directive sort = 'Username'></my-directive>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this after all.

```
.directive("myDirective", function () {

        return {
            scope:{prop:'@'},
            templateUrl:'/templates/Sorter.html'

        }

    });
```

and the html  like this.

```
<my-directive prop="UserName"></my-directive>
```